# reCaptcha works locally but no on server

Tags: recaptcha

I use reCaptcha for my login form . it works great locally but on server it returns `ReCaptchaResponse Object ( [success] => [errorCodes] => )`

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow_url_fopen` was disable in my server and by enabling it , problem was resovled